# Sending emails with an android app through company smtp server

Tags: android, email, kotlin, smtp

I need to find a suitable `smtp` library for my android project, which can connect to a specific company `smtp` server and send an email through it. I've tried a few of them and none of them worked. The company email I want to send emails from doesn't need a password.

I tried `javax.mail` library, maybe I just need to modify properties, code below:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host)
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", host)
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25")
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false")
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false")

val session = Session.getInstance(props)
```

There is no error, the application is loading indefinitely when I click send.

Comment: Plz try in thread

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: To avoid the stuck, use thread

Comment: No that's not the issue, I use `doAsync` to send the email, the issue is just the email isn't sending. I'll edit the post, I meant that the loading screen is loading indefinitely on the ui and the email never sends.